# Nintex workflow not able to import?

Tags: workflow

I have created nintex workflow in different domain in SharePoint but I want to export the same one to other domain site,

when I have imported In lower level environment its working fine but when I will try to import in production its not able to import the workflow

please let me know any settings missing.

Thanks 
Srinivas